# Framer Motion + Next.js - Page transition - layoutId and initial prop conflict

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

While developing an image page transitions with Framer motion and Next.js using `layoutId`, I'm running into an issue.

My basic goal:

1. Home page shows overview with 3 images
2. Click on image > fade out other images > scale up specific image and go to page with full size image.
3. Click on back link > scale down large image > fade in other images with a small delay.

[GIF animation of current proejct](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/861547719998046218/1008701497317531668/gif.gif)

Image size is transitioning well with `layoutId`, but if I define an opacity transitions using `initial`, `animate` and `exit` on all images (which also have a layoutId), it also applies the opacity values to the `layoutId` transition. As you can see in the gif my large image also becomes transparent

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Code on Github: https://github.com/sefrijn/next-page-animate

Deployed on Netlify: https://delicate-monstera-3b89b8.netlify.app/

Image component code:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function Image({ id }) {
  return (
    <motion.div
      layoutId={`wrapper_image_${id}`}
      transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}
      initial={{ opacity: 0.2 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0.2 }}
      className={"relative w-full h-full"}
    >
      <motion.img
        className={"h-full w-full object-cover"}
        src={`/mountain${id}.jpeg`}
      />
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Comment: When do you want to run opacity animation?

Comment: don't understand what you want to do, but it looks great as it is.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial If you look at the Netlify deploy, when you click "go back" on large image page, I want the large image to stay fully visible, so opacity 1. Only the small images should fade from transparent to fully visible... Hope this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself:

working GIF example

[image: 1]

I added a prop `main` to the Image components. This prop becomes `true` if the Image component is clicked (in index page) or active in full size.

By using this prop, Image components that are not clicked or in full size view animate using the variants. But the main Image component ignores the variants animation, and uses layoutId to automatically transition the position of the Image between pages.

When going back from single page to index page, I send a parameter along with the router, letting the index page know which Image was shown, in order to set `main` to true for the right Image component.

Full code: https://delicate-monstera-3b89b8.netlify.app/

Hope this helps anybody!

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function Image({ main = false, id }) {
  //  Conditionally enable or disable the motion props
  //  Main is true when this Image component is clicked or shown as full size
  const variants = {
    initial: !main ? { opacity: 0 } : null,
    animate: !main
      ? { opacity: 1, transition: { delay: 0.2 } }
      : { opacity: 1 },
    exit: !main ? { opacity: 0 } : null,
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      layoutId={`wrapper_image_${id}`}
      variants={variants}
      initial="initial"
      animate="animate"
      exit="exit"
      transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}
      className={"relative w-full h-full"}
    >
      <img
        className={"shadow-lg h-full w-full object-cover"}
        src={`/mountain${id}.jpeg`}
      />
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```